# DOCKER_WWWROOT giving error on docker-compose up -d "not set or not an existing directory"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

Docker, docker-compose have been installed according to docker docs for fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

When I try to run the compose command I get the following error:

`***DOCKER_WWWROOT is not set or not an existing directory.`

I have previously run `export ***DOCKER_WWWROOT=/path/to/myproject` and have conifrmed the path is correct by running `export`.

The `declare -x ***DOCKER_WWWROOT` value shows my correct path. The directory does exist.

Any help is appreciated. The ***'s are just placeholders for the template brand name.

Comment: What compose command?  What's in the `docker-compose.yml` file?  What image are you running, and what code actually produces the `... is not set ...` error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My install process was missing a step. Needed to add user group to run docker as a non-root user https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/
From the docker docs:
Create docker group `sudo groupadd docker`
Add user to group `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER Activate group changes` newgrp docker`Verify docker can be run without sudo commands`docker run hello-world`